# Create a Pure CSS Dropdown Menu - Children nodes don't appear

Tags: html, css

I've been teaching myself CSS and trying to create a drop-down menu.

I'm following [this page](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) and other tutorials, but the children nodes (sub lists) on my coding won't appear.

HTML and CSS look like following.

```
    <body>  
        <div id="menu">           
            <ul>
                <!-- 1st level -->
                <h2><li><a>Header</a></li></h2>  
                <li><b href="#">Home</b></li>              
                <li>
                    <b href="#">Patterns</b>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- 2nd level-->
                        <li><b href ="#">Event</b></li>
                        <li><b href ="#">Case</b></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </li>                    
                <!-- other menus --> 
            </ul>         
        </div> <!-- end menu -->     
    </body>
```

CSS

```css
menu {
        float: left;
    }

    #menu ul li {
        list-style-type: block;
        display: inline;
    }

    #menu li a {
        <!-- omit --> 
    }

    #menu li b {
        <!-- omit -->
    }

    #menu ul li :hover {
        background: #555;
    }

    #menu ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu ul li  :hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
```

At least I understand that, in `#menu ul li ul`, `display` needs to be `none`, but I'm clueless as to how to show it when I hover it.
I'd appreciate if you would give any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper HTML: (without `b` tags, this time)

```
<div id="menu">           
            <ul>
                <!-- 1st level -->
                <h2><li><a>Header</a></li></h2>  
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>              
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Patterns</a>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- 2nd level-->
                        <li><a href ="#">Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Case</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </li>                    
                <!-- other menus --> 
            </ul>         
        </div> <!-- end menu -->
```

And CSS:

```
#menu {
        float: left;
    }

    #menu ul li {
        list-style-type: block;
        display: inline;
    }

 #menu ul li:hover {
        background: #555;
    }

    #menu ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Basically - biggest problem *was space between selector and :hover pseudo class*. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LL34k5ku/4/